# Hide checkboxes when button is clicked

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView.Adapter` setted in a `RecycleView` which belongs to an `Activity`. This `Activity` contains a button. This adapter contains rows which have checkboxes. I would like to hide checkboxes of all rows when this button is clicked.
I'm using ViewHolder's pattern in my adapter.

I'm thinking in this solution:

Pass in my activity as a parameter to adapter's constructor. This activity contains a method to verify if button was clicked. And when this button is clicked the value changes and calls `notifyDataSetChanged()`. So the adapter shows/hides checkboxes.

Based on a MVP approach is this a good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- Each view holder is related to a model class. in this model class, you can hold a boolean that indicates if the corresponding view holder should show the checkbox.
  When the button is clicked you can iterate over the items that should be affected and change the boolean to true. Then notify data changed on the affected items.
- The adapter can hold a boolean that indicates if all the checkboxes should be hidden.
  Each view holder will receive the adapter as a reference upon creation (and not the activity - which is bad) and will check this boolean whether to show or hide the checkbox.
  The adapter boolean will be updated when the button is clicked and then will trigger a notify data changed.

Comment: In the first case the Activity creates and holds an instance of Adapter? In this way the button can call an Adapter menthod which iterates over tie items.

Comment: Yes.  Hold an instance of the adapter and then use its functionalities when needed (when the button clicked for example).